# Startup circuit 0 current mode

Tags: analog, cmos

I was designing the start up circuit for one of my circuits as shown in the figure below . I was able to understand how a start up works clearly but I stil havent figured out how exactly the 0 current state would be made possible.

I know that when the mentioned nodes reach Vdd or 0 volts then yes of course the current in the circuit would be 0 but what would cause these nodes to be Vdd and 0 ?

The circuit is a design of a bandgap reference. I just want to know how the mentioned nodes in the figure could reach Vdd or 0 Volts. If I understand this then I am clear with the entire startup issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrated circuits are powered from a power supply that is turned on at some point in time. Ideally such a power supply when turned on starts at zero volts and ramps up to the specified voltage.

So you have a power supply that is initially zero. If you have a circuit that has a stable operating point at such a voltage it will never leave that operating point. It won't start up.

In your bandgap circuit this operating point is possible. If the current mirrors have zero Vgs no current will flow and all the voltage will drop across drain-source. The diode connected transistors don't turn on, your circuit can't start up.

The diode connected transistor conduct a small current because of the subthreshold current. Therefore the PMOS transistors pull the drain nodes to VDD and the NMOS transistors pull the drain nodes to VSS.

A startup circuit will detect this condition and inject a current to get the circuit going. As soon as the circuit leaves the undesired operating point the startup circuit will be turned off.